# Issues implementing a search function "TypeError: data.filter is not a function"

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api, ecmascript-6

```
EDIT: heres the console.log(data) the data is displaying fine, it's just not filtering the data properly..]
!https://imgur.com/a/SsEDAKj!
```

EDIT 2: this.state.items is an array.

I'm trying to implement a search function, that allows the user to search through the data brought back from the API. I keep getting the following error:

> "TypeError: data.filter is not a function"

```
constructor(){

    super();

    this.state ={
        items: [],
        sessions: [],
        loading: true,
        search: '',
        direction: 'asc',
        filteredPosts: [],
        query: ''
    }

    this.onSort = this.onSort.bind(this);
    this.searchTerm = this.searchTerm.bind(this);
    //this.filteredPosts = this.filteredPosts.bind(this);

}

searchTerm =(event) =>{
    const query = event.target.value;
    this.setState({query}, () => this.filterData());
}

filterData(){
    let data = this.state.items;
    let src = this.state.query;

    data = data.filter(function(data){
        return data.indexOf(src) != -1;
    });
    this.setState({filteredPosts: data});
    console.log(this.state.filteredPosts);
}
async getTalks(){
    const response = await fetch ('PRIVATE_API');
    const data = await response.json();
    //console.log(data);
    this.setState({items: data});
}

async componentDidMount(){
    this.getTalks();

}

render(){
    return (

    <div className="container-fluid m-0">
        <div className="row h-100">
            <div className="col-12 ml-0"><h2>Conference Talks</h2>
            <p>You can search the talks via title, speaker or tags</p>
            <input className="form-control mb-2" id="search" type="text" onChange={this.searchTerm} placeholder="search"></input></div>
            <table className="table table-hover table-dark">
                <thead>
                </thead>
                <tbody id ="list">
            {this.state.items.map(function(item,index){
                    return(
                        <tr key = {index}>
                            <th data-title="id"scope="row">{item.id}</th>
                            <td data-title="title" style={{cursor: "pointer"}} title data-original-title={"Click to sort"} data-toggle="title" >{item.title}</td>
                            <td data-title="description" id="desc">{item.description}</td>
                            <td data-title ="speaker">{item.speaker}</td>
                            <td >{item.session}</td>
                            <td >{item.tags}</td>
                            <td >{item.time}</td>
                            <td >{avg}</td>
```

I can't figure out the right direction to go in when trying to filter through the data that is pulled. What mistakes am I making? ( I have only included relevent code)

Comment: In your `const data = await response.json();` `data` most probably is not an `array`.

Comment: Show us what does log that commented `console.log(data)`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/SsEDAKj

Comment: I think when you call `filterData()`, `this.state.items` is not an array.

Comment: I think you guys are right its not an array, ill try sort that just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I wasn't returning the object attribute.

```
data = data.filter(function(data){
        return **data.title**.toLowerCase().indexOf(src) !== -1;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you run a check to see if your data is there?  It's possible the items are not available on first render, causing this problem.  Maybe something like

```
{this.state.items.length > 0 && this.state.items.map(function(item,index){
//rest of your code here
```

Also, I noticed you are bringing in a loading variable.  If this is working you could do

```
if(loading){ return (<LoadingComponent />}else{ //regular return statement
```

Comment: All of the data is there, all the data is pushed into the state variable "items=[]" and its displaying in my table with no issues. I don't think i explained it well enough, but theres an input box, and i want to filter the user search by matching it with the results inside "items[]" - cheers